# Get Email from id_token Gmail OAuth

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I have a JSON Object with following details:

```
{ access_token: 'access_token',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expires_in: 3599,
  id_token: 'longstring' 
}
```

Using NodeJs library 'googleapis' how can I get the email address for the above response. I do not want to use the URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=your_access_token

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why don't you want to use requests to regular urls? :) I personally think it's easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an auth-object like in the [introduction](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample), and then you can use the [getProfile](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/gmail/v1.js) method:

```
function getEmailAddress(auth, callback) {
  gmail.users.getProfile({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      callback(null, response.emailAddress)
    }
  });
}
```